# Adding to List<string> but having trouble with the items getting added

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, foreach

I have 2 lists with 200 items in each.
List A contains the names of the products.
List B contains the prices of the products.

I have another list (List C) with 250 items inside which include names and prices of products.

Now, I am trying to compare the names of List A to see if they exist in List C and if they do I want to use the price in List C.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
foreach (var item in wiznzList)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < nameList.Count; j++)
    {
        if (nameList[j] == item.ProductName)
        {
            wizNzPriceList.Add(item.Price);
        }
        else
        {
            wizNzPriceList.Add("No Product");
        }
    }
}
```

I want to go through the list of names and check if they exist in List C if they do I want to add the price from List C and if it doesn't exist I want it to write No Product.

So, in the end I want 3 lists with 200 items in each.

Instead, when I run this I get 10040000 items added into the list. Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: did you try put a `break;` after your .Add(). You can also use `if (nameList.Contains(item.ProductName))` instead of the inner for loop.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick reply. I have tried Contains() but because the names of the products are similar I have changed to using == instead. Adding break; gives me 50200 items instead of 10040000.

Comment: Hey there welcome to stack overflow please read [mcve].  You can edit your post to include data for your lists to help reproduce the issue.

Comment: As far as i can tell, ListB isn't functionally being used, why do we care about it?

Comment: So List A is a list containing 200 products from 1 website and List B contains the prices for these products. List C contains 250 products and prices from a different website.

Comment: Create a set of *much* smaller lists (5 or 10 elements) that show the same issues. That's the *minimal* part of [mcve]

Comment: what do you mean by _the names of the products are similar_?

Comment: the issue here is that you're adding too many "No Product" for each product you're trying to match you'll get "No Product" foreach element other that your element.. you should be using `Contains()` instead, or explain your original problem more

Comment: by similar I mean -
some product names are Toothpaste, Toothpaste X 2, Toothpaste X 3.
as you can see If I use contains, it will be true for all 3 products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a code that does what you want it to do !

Object Product(string pName, float pPrice).

listA list of Products so you can store and change price.

listB list of float, not used.

list C list of Products with pName and pPrice.

The CompareA_With_C() method first checks for same products and if true put price of list C in listA and breaks out of inner loop.

The else if statement waits till the loop has gone through the whole of listC and if no pName match found, changes pName to "No Product" in listA.

Code :

```
 void CompareA_With_C()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < listA.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < listC.Count; j++)
                {
                    string a = listA[i].pName;
                    string c = listC[j].pName;

                    if (string.Equals(a, c))
                    {
                        listA[i].pPrice = listC[j].pPrice;
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (j == (listC.Count - 1))
                    {
                        listA[i].pName = "No Product";
                        listB[i] = 0.0f;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: PS : The noob is me :)
Also, I'm not sur about the .add() sounds like increasing the # of items,isn't there somth like .replace() ?  but hey, I haven't yet studied list yet  :(

Comment: Hello, I have tried this and it is giving me 50400 results.
If i use a for loop and put the foreach loop inside it gives me too many results.
Thank you for your reply :) , I am a big Noob also haha

Comment: Changed my answer totally, now it works ! Could be written more compact probably but the grey cells are tired now :)
PS : you can replace Products in listA with just strings and adjust code a bit.

Comment: Removed unnecessary code, this is the best I can do as beginner :)

Comment: Hi thank you for your time looking into this , i will try this now :)

Comment: Glad it works ! And no problem, I had loads of fun doing this and learned a lot about lists, loops, classes, I should thank you for the problem presented, most of the stuff on this site is still way to esoteric for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your problem correctly (and the jury is out on that)

You could use `ToDictionary` and `Select`

```
var dict = products.ToDictionary(x => x.ProductName, x => x.Price);
var results = names.Select(x => dict.TryGetValue(x, out var value) ? value.ToString() : "No Product");
```

<sub>***Note*** : You could use `Any` for O(n^2) time complexity. However, `ToDictionary` would be more efficient</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use LINQ and replace your inner loop with [`Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8) method.

```cs
foreach (var item in wiznzList)
{
    if (nameList.Any(p => p == item.ProductName)
    {
        wizNzPriceList.Add(item.Price);
    }
    else
    {
        wizNzPriceList.Add("No Product");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, unfortunately this is giving me the same results.

Comment: @SJKim there is no way the code in this question can lead to "10040000 items added into the list"...

Comment: Hi you were right, i had it placed in a For loop i think which made it give 10040000 items. I now get a result of 253 items which is the amount of items in List C. I am still trying to figure out how I can only get 200 results..

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by using the code below, Thank you very much Crispi.

```
for (int i = 0; i < nameList.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < wiznzList.Count; j++)
            {
                string a = nameList[i];
                string c = wiznzList[j].ProductName;

                if (string.Equals(a, c))
                {
                    wizNzPriceList.Add(wiznzList[j].Price);
                    break;
                }
                else if (j == (wiznzList.Count - 1))
                {
                    wizNzPriceList.Add("No Product");
                }
            }
        }
```

I now get 200 results as required. Thank you everyone for your time.